# Facebook Account Kit in Swift

Tags: swift, authentication, sms, facebook-login, account

I couldn't get the Account Kit's delegate methods to get called. I might be wrong but I think this is because of the delegate methods didn't get translated correctly from Objective-C into Swift. Here is the code samples:

```
import AccountKit
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, AKFViewControllerDelegate {

    let accountKit = AKFAccountKit(responseType: .AuthorizationCode)
    var pendingLoginViewController: UIViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pendingLoginViewController = accountKit.viewControllerForLoginResume()
    }

    @IBAction func loginWithEmail(sender: AnyObject) {
        let viewController = accountKit.viewControllerForEmailLoginWithEmail(nil, state: generateState()) as! AKFViewController
        viewController.enableSendToFacebook = true
        viewController.delegate = self
        presentViewController(viewController as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func generateState() -> String {
        let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
        let indexOfDash = uuid.rangeOfString("-")!.startIndex
        return uuid.substringToIndex(indexOfDash)
    }

    func viewController(viewController: UIViewController!, didCompleteLoginWithAuthorizationCode code: String!, state: String!) {
        // This function doesn't get called when user finished their login
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try additionaly implement other 3 delegate methods. I quickly tried this. Failure callback is called for me (#3). That's fine as I did not complete proper SDK initialization. May be you experience same situation, so that you view controller receives failure callback. As that callback is not implemented you are not aware of it:

```
func viewController(viewController: UIViewController!, didCompleteLoginWithAuthorizationCode code: String!, state: String!) {
    print("1")
}

func viewController(viewController: UIViewController!, didCompleteLoginWithAccessToken accessToken: AKFAccessToken!, state: String!) {
    print("2")
}

func viewController(viewController: UIViewController!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    print("3")
}

func viewControllerDidCancel(viewController: UIViewController!) {
    print("4")
}
```

Comment: None of these callbacks get called for me. Can you show me your setup code?

Comment: Are you getting the dialog view controller presented? If so, try to enter some wrong email address  - I am getting #3 callback. After that you can try "Cancel" - callback #4 is called for me. BTW I use Swift 2.2 compiler (latest one). Also you can try to mark the delegate methods implementation with @objc keyword.

Comment: Thank you. I got it works. In my original code I set the `responseType ` to a wrong value. I set it to `AuthorizationCode ` but was waiting for a callback on `AccessToken `.

Comment: @Thi I am sorry if this is inappropriate, but how do you get the user inputted phone number from the callback?

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong. I set `responseType` to `.AuthorizationCode` but was waiting for a callback on `.AccessToken`.

Answer (score 1):

@JayVDiyk:
How do you get the user inputted phone number from the callback? –

Answer: You can get that from the accountkit object by requestAccount menthod

```html
accountKit.requestAccount({ account, error in
                print("Account number \(account?.accountID)")
                print("Email: \(account?.emailAddress)")
                print("Phone: \(account?.phoneNumber?.stringRepresentation())")
})
```